# DialogFragment "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class TextView"

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-dialogfragment, inflate-exception

I have subclassed DialogFragment.  It works fine on some phones, but throws "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class TextView" on others.  There are two odd things. First, there are no TextViews in my project.  Second, the line #25 does not even exist in my layout file (it only goes up to 22!).  How on earth is this possible?

Here is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="List Name:"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Create"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my DialogClass:

```
public class AddStoreDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_store_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
}

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

Here is the complete exception stack:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class TextView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3605)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:397)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:388)
   at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:501)
   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:389)
   at mjh.com.listory.MyLists.AddStoreDialogFragment.onActivityCreated(AddStoreDialogFragment.java:48)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2089)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1133)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=22; index=263
   at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
   at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:991)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getText(TypedArray.java:144)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:921)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:632)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:59)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:55)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
   at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3605) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:397) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:388) 
   at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:501) 
   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:389) 
   at mjh.com.listory.MyLists.AddStoreDialogFragment.onActivityCreated(AddStoreDialogFragment.java:48) 
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2089) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1133) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290) 
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```